# Find the row or column with the largest number of zeros and expand the determinant of the matrix over it.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the row or column with the largest number of zeros and expand the determinant of the matrix over it. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}4&1&0\\2&3&2\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

The answer must be written in order of the determinants of the corresponding matrices $2 \times 2$ and determinant of the whole matrix.

I decided and my answer is $ 10, 2, 8, -10$, but the test said me that it is a wrong answer. I don't understand why my answer has been wrong. Please, say me why i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just expand it around the bottom row $0,0,-1$. Which would just yield $-10$ as the on sub-determinant

Comment: Yes, I did so. I got 10.

Comment: But it is $-10$

Comment: Why? 12 - 2 = 10

Comment: You need to calculate $-1*(12-2)=-10$

Comment: Exactly! Thank you a lot, bro!